# Texify IDEA: how to apply custom code style?

Tags: intellij-idea, latex, code-formatting

I'm using the very useful plugin "texify IDEA" for working with latex code inside IntelliJ. It works very fine for all my needs. Unfortunately, in Editor -> Code Style section of the options I cannot find Latex... so I cannot set my custom code style rules. I've tried to search online without success... how can I resolve this?

Comment: Most likely the plugin simply does not have this feature implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking as the author of TeXiFy-IDEA: what yole said is correct. This is a feature that is not yet implemented and therefore is not supported by the plugin. You can either wait for the developers to add this functionality, or add it yourself.

I would highly recommend [visiting the GitHub page](https://github.com/Ruben-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/issues) of the plugin if you have questions/feature requests/bug reports for faster and better support.